# How to configure Sleuth to trace AWS SQS queues

Tags: amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-aws

I am trying to trace Spring cloud integration aws + AWS SQS app with Sleuth. The receiver receives message from SQS after a message is added to queue. The log has app name, but no trace id and span id while receiving message from sql queue. Here is a line from the log:

2017-07-28 16:24:02.352  INFO [sqs-sleuth-demo,,,] 9706 --- [enerContainer-2] com.example.demo.SQSMessageReceiver      : dequeued message: hello world

I use Spring Boot '1.5.4.RELEASE' and Spring Cloud 'Dalston.SR1'. Here is the dependencies:

```
dependencies {

  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging")
  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure")
  compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth')
  compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-aws:1.0.0.RELEASE")

  compile("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs")
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
  }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
  private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

  @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
  private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

  @Value("${amazon.sqs.endpoint}")
  private String amazonSqsEndpoint;

  @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}")
  private String awsRegion;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public AWSCredentialsProviderChain credentialsProviderChain() {

    return new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
  }
}
```

SQSMessageReceiver.java

```
@Component
public class SQSMessageReceiver {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SQSMessageReceiver.class);

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @SqsListener(value="${amazon.sqs.queue.name}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)

  public void receive(String message) throws Exception {

    LOGGER.info("dequeued message: " + message);

  }
}
```

and, DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSqs
public class DemoApplication {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

  }
}
```

Is it possible to trace SQS events with Sleuth or anything wrong with the setting/code?

Thanks,

Comment: If you're using Spring Cloud Sleuth & Spring Integration it should work out of the box. Sleuth has a global channel interceptor that appends headers to the outgoing message. Assuming that the SQS broker doesn't remove these headers the recipient should be able to parse the messaging headers and continue the trace. Can you verify that the outgoing and incoming message has tracing headers set?

Comment: Thank you Marcin.  Checked headers of the outgoing message that is returned by MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build(), and found there are no tracing infomation appended to the message headers. By explicitly adding tracing messages (traceId, spanId, and spanName) to header, they do appear in the message queued in AWS SQS. When does the channel interceptor append headers, during building or sending message?

Comment: Before sending the message. There's no interceptor for message building

Comment: Stepped into AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelnterceptorChain.applyPreSend() and found interceptors.size = 0. Should this be the place to add tracing messages? Did I miss something in the configuration or code?

Comment: Can you post your sample somewhere? And some instructions on how to try to replicate the problem?

Comment: Is this issue resolved?